# How to register Handlebars helper?

Tags: express, helper, express-handlebars, handlebarshelper

I searched the whole internet and no solution works. I have the following helper:

```
 Handlebars.registerHelper('ifeq', function (a, b, options) {
        if (a == b) { return options.fn(this); }
        return options.inverse(this);
    });
```

I want to use helper in my .hbs file:

```
 {{#ifeq variable "string"}} 
        ... do this ... 
    {{/ifeq}}
```

Where do I insert first piece of code, if I want to use that helper in my .hbs file? I've tried various ways, but every time I get the error: "Missing helper: ifeq".

Comment: You have an `express` tag, are you using handlebars in Node.js? Or is this a browser project?

Comment: @mmomtchev I'm using handlebars in Node.js.

Comment: Wherever you like. Just make sure it is before the loading of the `hbs` file. You can put it right after the `require('handlebars)`. How do you load your `hbs` file?